# Error while launching demo.launch in custom moveit config

Tags: ros, urdf, moveit, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have generated a moveit configuration from a custom URDF using the MoveIt Setup assistant and this tutorial(http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot).
I have been able to generate all the files in the config and launch folders as well. But, the problem occurs when I try to launch the demo.launch file using roslaunch.

Since this is a custom URDF, there's no package name, hence I simply use this command to launch the file

```
roslaunch ./launch/demo.launch
```

Everytime I try to do this, I get an error like this

```
... logging to /home/tarang/.ros/log/4bbd5ee2-924a-11e6-9522-4ceb427f02d3/roslaunch-HP-dv6-19948.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid <arg> tag: manip_moveit_config
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/tarang/ros_try/urdftry/robotis_try/catkin_Ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks. 

Arg xml is <arg default="$(find manip_moveit_config)/default_warehouse_mongo_db" name="db_path"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Here, `manip_moveit_config` is the name of the folder in which I saved my moveit config (in the last step of the setup assistant)

What am I missing here? Do I need to perform any other steps(besides those mentioned in the tutorial) to get it to work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245740/error-while-launching-demo.launch-in-custom-moveit-config/) by [t27](https://answers.ros.org/users/27290/t27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2016-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2016-10-14**:
Possible confusion, but shouldn't demo.launch be in the ROS package manip_moveit_config?

roslaunch manip_moveit_config demo.launch

**Comment by [t27](https://answers.ros.org/users/27290/t27/) on 2016-10-15**:
Thats the problem, I havent generated a package. Its only a folder where the moveit setup assistant exported the config files. Although the folder does have a CMakeLists and a package.xml file. How do i convert this file structure to a Ros "package"? cant I directly run a launch file?

**Comment by [t27](https://answers.ros.org/users/27290/t27/) on 2016-10-15**:
If i run `roslaunch manip_moveit_config demo.launch`
I getthis

```
> roslaunch manip_moveit_config demo.launch
[demo.launch] is neither a launch file in package [manip_moveit_config] nor is [manip_moveit_config] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Since this is a custom URDF, there's no package name,

I don't understand this.

"custom" urdfs should still be stored in a ROS package.

The MSA generates regular ROS packages, so you should be able to launch them using

```
roslaunch manip_moveit_config demo.launch
```

Have you (re)built your workspace and `source`d the `setup.bash` after you generated the package?

---

Edit:

> By custom urdf, I mean I have a urdf file which I imported to the MSA(It didnt need any package name).

The MSA tries to automatically resolve in which package the urdf lives. That is why you didn't need to supply it with a package name.

Or are you saying that your urdf is stored in your home directory, or at the root of your workspace, without any package(s) at all?

> Now the MSA generates a set of files into a configured folder with the CMakelists and package files I used the folder name `manip_moveit_config`.

That "set of files into a configured folder" is really a ROS package.

> Should I make a workspace with these files in /src? And should i then rebuild and source the setup files of this workspace?

Yes. Afterwards, you should be able to launch `demo.launch` succesfully.

---

Edit:

> Yes, putting the generated folder into a package file structure (as mentioned [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage) ) works.

Hm. The MSA should have generated a complete ROS package for you. If that was not the case, then it'd be nice if you could report that at [ros-planning/moveit/issues](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues).

> Also before running the launch file, I had to ensure `roscore` is running(I'd got stuck once, because it wasn't running)

If you use `roslaunch` to start a launch file, starting `roscore` should be done automatically. Again, if that is not the case for you, that would seem to be a problem, and it'd be appreciated if you could report that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [t27](https://answers.ros.org/users/27290/t27/) on 2016-10-15**:
By custom urdf, I mean I have a urdf file which I imported to the MSA(It didnt need any package name). Now the MSA generates a set of files into a configured folder with the CMakelists and package files I used the folder name `manip_moveit_config`. Should I make a workspace with these files in /src?

**Comment by [t27](https://answers.ros.org/users/27290/t27/) on 2016-10-15**:
And should i then rebuild and `source` the setup files of this workspace?

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2016-10-15**:
Yes, give this a try for sure. When gvdhoorn says custom URDFs should be stored in a ROS package, he is correct. This is because demo.launch looks for URDF in a launch file from another ROS package. You will either have to replace this with correct location or make a package for it (very easy).

**Comment by [t27](https://answers.ros.org/users/27290/t27/) on 2016-10-24**:
Yes, putting the generated folder into a package file structure (as mentioned [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage) ) works. Also before running the launch file, I had to ensure `roscore` is running(I'd got stuck once, because it wasn't running)
Thanks!

**Comment by [t27](https://answers.ros.org/users/27290/t27/) on 2016-10-25**:
`Hm. The MSA should have generated a complete ROS package for you. If that was not the case, then it'd be nice if you could report that at ros-planning/moveit/issues.`
MSA generates a package,I meant that I needed to move that folder to ./src/ in my workspace and run catkin_make to make it work